# MySQL reports a syntax error

Tags: mysql

I ran the following command and its reporting a syntax error:
mysql -u root cora_pe_crt12 -e "delete * from $table where snapshot_id <= 101 and tenant_id = 1";

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from nameoftable where snapshot_id <= 101 and tenant_id = 1' at line 1

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation of the `DELETE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)? The answer is right there, in the first lines of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Delete command.Try this

> delete from $table where snapshot_id <= 101 and tenant_id = 1;

Comment: I removed the * and the following error started getting reported: ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'tenant_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Also ERROR 1451 (23000) at line 1: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cora_pe_crt12`.`lb_param`, CONSTRAINT `lb_param_group_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`snapshot_id`, `tenant_id`, `group_id`) REFERENCES `lb_group` (`snapshot_id`, `tenant_id`, `id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON )
ERROR 1451 (23000) at line 1: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cora_pe_crt12`.`lfdef_server_assoc`, CONSTRAINT `lfdef_server_assoc_lfdef_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`snapshot_id`, `tenant_id`, `lfdef_id`) REFERENCES `lfdef` (`snapshot_id`, `tenant_id`, `id`) ON DEL)

Comment: According to error ,there is foreign key attached to the table. You need to delete the records from the table first and then try delete stuff from current table.

Comment: Thats gone ..now I see only ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'tenant_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Are u sure that column is called as 'tenant_id'?

Comment: Yes...I confirmed again...Its called tenant_id

Comment: Is it tenant or tenant_id?

Comment: try this one delete from $table where `snapshot_id` <= '101' and `tenant_id` = '1'. or delete from $table where snapshot_id <= 101 having tenant_id = 1

Comment: If you could post of the design of the your database it will be better to understand.

Comment: Very Very Strange but it worked. Following your same above command, I just changed the single quotes to double quote and it worked. delete from $table where snapshot_id <= "101" and tenant_id = "1"

Answer (score 0):

Delete command is not correct and you do not need `*`

```
delete from $table where snapshot_id <= 101 and tenant_id = 1
```